# Python Joblib causing loop

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, joblib

I'm working with joblib to load a sklearn classifier. I have this in a class but it seems to keep calling the class's `__init__` function. Here's an illustration:

```
class MyContainer(object):
    FILENAME = "classifier.pkl"

    def __init__(self):
        self._load()

    def _load(self):
        self._classifier = joblib.load(self.FILENAME)
```

For some reason when I call joblib.load(self.FILENAME), pickle tries to instantiate the whole class again. This causes the problem because it will call `__init__` again and then try to load the classifier again.

I'm not really sure why this is happening. Any ideas? Thanks for any help and let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: What's in "classifer.pkl"?

Comment: Is it possible that joblib.load calls the __init__() method of it's restored instance? If so, remove the `self._load()` call from your `__init__()` method.